# How to make a layout floating inside the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am trying to make a login activity containing two fields (username, password) and a button.

I have encapsulated them with a linear layout.

I want to know how to make this layout floating inside the parent activity/view so that if the user tries to drag in a particular direction, it follows the user's input towards the end of the screen and then slowly moves back to its original central position.

Comment: here you go, please check this example i wrote awhile ago.
https://github.com/k0shk0sh/AndroidFloatingImage

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me.But it is not moving automatically towards the original central position,what should I have to do for automatic positioning.

Comment: U can change the params.x and params.y to do so. Use paramd.gravity to center it.

Comment: will this work on a liniar layout?

Comment: Yes it will for.any layout.

Comment: its not working I am sorry.I tried to pass the layout to the FloatingImage class but the layout is not moving.Only there is made a square which is moving .not the whole layout.

Comment: You have to extend linearlayout not imageView. You want to move your layout not am image view. So extend linear layout

Comment: ohhkk and what should I have to do with 
this.setImageResource(R.id.layoutlogin1);
I am sorry I am new to androids

Comment: Sir If I remove this line then how will I pass the layout which I want  to be float.